# How is time slice divided among the pthreads in a process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix, glibc

Is the Linux kernel aware of pthreads in the user address space ( which i dont think it is..but i did not find any info abt that). How does the Instruction pointer change when thread switching takes place.. ??

Comment: While there is no scheduling difference between threads and processes, you can group threads/processes into control groups, each of which will be treated by the scheduler as an "accounting entity", i.e. it will charge the whole control group for the CPU time, so if you group, e.g. a maven invocation (which creates lots of threads), the remaining control groups will get a fairer share of the CPU time.

Answer (score 5):

The native NPTL (native posix thread library) used in Linux maps pthreads to "processes that share resources and therefore look like threads" in the kernel. In this way, the kernel's scheduler directly controls the scheduling of pthreads.

A "pthread switch" is done by the exact same code (in the kernel) that handles process switches. Simplified, this would be something like "store previous process state; if the next process uses a different virtual address space then switch virtual address spaces; load next process state;" (where "process state" includes the instruction pointer for the process/thread).

Comment: It's just how Linux has always done threads. I did find some references though. 1) scroll down to "5 Linux" at http://www.icir.org/gregor/tools/pthread-scheduling.html. 2) scroll down to "Linux Implementations of POSIX Threads" at http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads.

Answer (score 2):

Well the Linux kernel doesn't know about user threads (pthread does in userspace, moreover the kernel doesn't really care about them except it just needs to know what to schedule).

The instruction pointer is changed in the kernel during what's called a context switch. During this switch the kernel essentially asks the scheduler what's next? the scheduler will hand it a task_struct which contains all the information about the thread and the interrupt handler for a context switch will go ahead and set the values on the CPU accordingly (page tables, instruction pointer, etc...) and when that code is done the CPU simply just starts executing from there.

Comment: So you essential mean to say.. one thread gets hold of one full time slice, the process was alloted with? and there is no time slice dividing among the threads with in a process?

Comment: @SpinLocked The kernel doesn't care if it's a process or thread (it actually makes no distinction) it only cares about priority(amount of time to give the thread) and if it's schedulable or not (waiting for I/O or something).

Comment: Thanks. I probably mis-stated the question. Apologies. i intend to know the thread level scheduling work. Is it plain time slice to thread mapping or, is there any intelligence at the process level, which gives each thread a share of the time.

Answer (score 1):

1) The kernel doesn't know about user-level threads. However, NPTL isn't user level

2) This is a really broad question. You should look at an OS book. It will go into depth on that issue and all other involved in a context switch.

Comment: hey Thanks!! AFAIK, OS books cover abt the process context switching. but was wondering, how is the time slice managment among the threads taking place.. if the kernel is not aware of the thread, is it some thing like partly, scheduler activations?? if not how is the process, able to manage and book keep the threads. and more over i feel, this is more related to the user level programming.. so, asked the question here..

Comment: If you are interested in learning about how linux does these things, check out Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love. It's covers a lot, but is pretty accessible. Enjoy.